# How do I find the sum of all the subsquares in a matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, matlab, matrix

I am looking to find the sum of all subsquares of an extremely large matrix, in which

{ {1, 2}
{3,4} } in a 2D matrix would return 20. I have achieved this using java, but the program is very slow. Is there a faster way to do so, or another language that would be faster?

```
public class insaneMat
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] mat = new int[10000][10000];

    try
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("file.in"));  
        int count = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < mat.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c <mat[r].length; c++)
            {
                mat[r][c] = input.nextInt();
                count++;
                System.out.println("Loaded num " + count);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
    }

    int n = mat.length;
    int k;
    int sum = 0;
    for (k = 1; k < 10000; k++)
    {
        System.out.println("Calculating with subsquare of size " + k);
        for (int i=0; i<n-k+1; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<n-k+1; j++)
            {
                for (int p=i; p<k+i; p++)
                    for (int q=j; q<k+j; q++)
                        sum += mat[p][q];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number = " + sum);

}
```

This works as intended in java, except it is very, very slow. The program works for a 2x2 matrix, as provided above, but runs about 30 subsquares per hour. Can it be done in a faster method, regardless of whether I use java or a different language? Would Matlab be useful?

Comment: May we ask why you need to do this?  This problem could get untangible very quickly, as it appears to scale with the factorial of the length of the square.

Comment: Can you furnish one training file "file.in" ? But more important, can you clarify what you need and what you are doing here, because from the code I see there, I don't undertand "would return 20".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve this is to work out *analytically* how many subsquares of a matrix of size N each element[i,j] will belong to ... call this function C(n, i,j).  Then work out the sum of C(n, i, j) * element[i, j] over all i, j.

The complexity of the computation will be `O(N^2)` ... compared with your current algorithm's `O(N^5)` (And I suspect that the algorithm might be wrong ... if you want all subsquares from 1 to N-1 ... and the true complexity is O(N!).)

Anyhow, all you need is a bit of mathematics :-)

---

Warning, these sums are going to get exceedingly large.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the part where "The way to solve this is to work out analytically how many subsquares of a matrix of size N each element[i,j] will belong to". Could you provide an example as to how this works?

Comment: "Solve this analytically" means "do the math" to work out the system of formulae.  The problem should amenable to an inductive proof, but I'm not going to do it for you!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is O(n^5) algorithm,  those tend to be very slow.  Matlab will help because it is super optimized for Matrix operations. However, to get the maximum speed you will need to write vectorized code, meaning that two of your inner loops should be compressed into something like this  sum(sum(M[i:k+i,j:k+j])) If you don't have lots of money for Matlab, these days numpy tends to be very fast.

Another observation that Stephen C mentioned, is that you are computing same thing over and over again.  For example sum of elements of submatrix M[2:3,3:4] is also useful for submatrices M[1:3,3:4] and M[1:5,1:8] etc.  So you need to keep tabs on those intermediate results.   Look up Memoization and Dynamic Programming for the exact techniques and the theory behind it.

The easiest almost automated way to do it is through memoization.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization  Which is essentially making your inner loops into separate methods.  This methods keep a record of arguments they were called with and the received results.  So that next time they called with the same parameters they can just look up the result without doing actual calculation.  Many functional languages have a library that turns regular function into memoized one.  Looks like it is now possible to do in Java 8 as well with new functional extensions https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization

Comment: I understand that I would be repeatedly calculating numerous subsquares, but I was unable to identify how to keep a tab on these and prevent recalucalting these squares